# Assignment Rule and Campaign Member Equal Do Not Call

Tags: community, leads, campaign, assignment-rules, campaign-member

I have trouble figure out how to set up an assignment rule that route my leads with campaign member status equal "Do Not Call".  I've created a "Do Not Call" status on campaign member object and created a queue "Do Not Call".

While setting up this assignment rule, I can only see campaign object and not campaign member object in the drop down selection.  Is there another to setup this assignment rule?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

So, when I create an assignment rule, I didn't think to look for campaign member status in the Lead grouping.  Therefore, I thought it was available to create rule on.  So, look under Lead: Campaign member status.